# Rendering my world according to my model

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I have two questions:

The first being why exactly my Box2D Body is twice the size of my GameObjects size? I am probably doing something wrong, but it seems odd that the two are aligned perfectly, so the units between my model and my renderer match up.

Second question I have, is if I can somehow change the projection the SpriteBatch uses to place objects on the screen, instead of moving my camera?

The picture here explain my two problems quite well

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you used setAsBox() method on your PolygonShape. this method only takes the half-width and half-height of the box. So if you give it the full size, it will be twice as large and twice as high.
2. `spritebatch.setProjectionMatrix()`

Comment: Ahh yes, didn't quite read the specifications to setAsBox() :)

Comment: As for the projection of the SpriteBatch, I remembered from XNA that I could somehow make it generate a projection matrix using `Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(width, height, ...)` Doesn't libgdx have something alike?

Comment: `spritebatch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrdo2D()`, if I remember well.